# How to change width of td, when I using bootstrap to fixed header of table?

Tags: html, html-table, fixed, column-width

The Table is done with bootstrap, every 2 td corresponds to a th, but I would like to change the width of one of the td into 40px. I tried for a long time (probably one day), but still can not work, who can help me?

[h2.html](http://eeeie.com/h2.html)

[image: image of the html]

Comment: Please add the HTML to your question so we can see it rather than link to a page containing it! Use the [edit] button and the `{}` tool to update the question.

Comment: Hi Brian : Thank you for your advice, this is my first question, some expressions do not abide by the rules, please forgive me, next time I will improve.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `table-layout` rule from `table`. Also remove html attributes `width, valign, bgcolor` because all are deprecated attributes. Instead of them use css.

```
.table td{
max-width: 40px;
background-color: #ddd;
vertical-align: top;/* Default value in Bootstrap 3 */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, You are great !